# map.setZoom() is not working but map.setCenter() is working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

Part of my code looks like this, I am able to center the map using

```
map.setCenter(myLatlng);
```

but after that I am trying to zoom the map

```
marker_id = id;
marker_id = new google.maps.Marker();

marker_id.setIcon(image);
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loctionupdateobj[id].lat, loctionupdateobj[id].lang);
marker_id.setPosition(myLatlng);        
marker_id.setMap(map);      

map.setCenter(myLatlng);

alert(map.getZoom());
map.setZoom(10);
alert("game again " + map.getZoom())
```

You can see the

```
alert("game again " + map.getZoom())
```

in the code it is giving me an alert like `game again 10` but the zoom level is never going to `10`.

But the first alert is `4` (which I set during initialsation).

As I am not able to `setZoom`, I am creating a new map instance each time when I am adding new markers.

Comment: did you set minZoom or maxZoom for the map?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem (or provide a complete example that does)

Comment: Try creating one map instance and add all markers to the same map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found !!!
The previous programmer who coded my project wrote a line

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(map);
```

Comment: This one was almost impossible to debug. While clearListeners is useful for freeing up memory it effectively disables a large portion of v3 core functionality. Thanks for battling this one out!

Comment: Encounter same issue for 3.17 & 3.18 too. This is really buggy.

Answer (score 1):

My map works with the places api and is looking for a location.
I first initialize my map with `zoom : 23`.

Once I search and submit my location the map defaults to its original zoom. So i had to use `map.setZoom(23)`, It was working at first then just stopped.

It's strange because `map.fitBounds()` works perfectly.

```
  setTimeout(function(){
      map.setZoom(23);                
      console.log('zoomed');
  },1);
```

My dirty solution for the time being.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ye same by me. I wonder how bad this Google API is coded if properties delaying at instance object.

Answer (score 0):

So the second alert is retuning 10, what is the first alert returning, is this 10 too?

If so you're zoom is already 10 (sorry if it's a stupid question, but no mention of this).

Comment: In that case check the map options e.g. maxZoom. Are you getting any other errors that might be blocking this call, is the zoom not working on all browsers, have you tried setting the value in developer tools when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can try calling the setZoom method after all the markers have been plotted on the map and all the other methods such as setCenter, bounds.extend are called. So u have to call setZoom method in the last marker function.